# How to confirm that file download completed successfully with webextensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download, firefox-addon-webextensions

[downloads.download()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download) would seem to be the easiest function to use for non-interactively dowloading & saving files in a webextension. However, it isn't the most-user friendly function in terms of error-handling. If I understand the documentation correctly, it resolves successfully once a download has *started*--but that doesn't mean that the download will *complete* successfully. And it only returns the id of the downloadItem object that has started to download, not a pointer to the object itself, which would seem to be what would be the more useful. (To get the object itself, I have been running downloads.search() queries based on the id. This extra step seems inefficient.)

In my tests, I am finding that even in the simple case of trying to download a file when supplying a url that points to a page-not-found (error 404) address, downloads.download() will happily download "a file" and resolve the promise with no error. The downloadItem's status will show "completed," the file will be shown as "exists," and the error status will be "undefined" (if following the change in the downloadItem's properties using an onChanged listener)--but inspection of the contents of the 4kb file that was generated will indicate that it was all just a 404 error.

My current strategy has been to attempt to download a file, wait for a listener to fire on a change to downloads items' statuses, and check the completion-status and errors properties for the downloadItems. But this all just seems hacky and inefficient. And I still haven't figured out the best way to efficiently detect, for example, 404 errors.

Is there an easier way to safely complete file downloads with webextensions that I am missing, maybe some API that I have overlooked?

(I have been trying to do this in Firefox webextensions, but if it's easier with chrome, I will try it that way instead.)

Comment: You may want to check the other property of the [DownloadItem](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download): states - Indicates whether the download is progressing, interrupted, or complete; bytesReceived - Number of bytes received so far from the host, without considering file compression. These are the properties that can help you check whether the download is complete or successful. You can also check this [GitHub](https://github.com/orbitbot/chrome-extensions-examples) that compiles all Chrome extension samples into one repository. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you think using onChanged is "hacky an inefficient"?  I can't see how any other API wouldn't just duplicated what onChanged already does.  The question about detecting 404's is a good one, its probably not a common case, but I could see an extension wanting to download an error page...  But distinguishing those two cases would require adding a new option to the download() API.